# python: Sum of products of values in two nested lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

1. I want sum of products (sop) of values of two nested lists.
2. Shift second list to the left by one after each iteration.
3. Store result of each sop in a list

I have two list like:

```
   List1 = [[A,1],[B,2],[C,3]]
   List2 = [[A,4],[B,5],[C,6]]
```

I am expecting this:

```
   iteration1 -> 
   List1 = [[A,1],[B,2],[C,3]]
   List2 = [[A,4],[B,5],[C,6]]
   sop = (1*4)+(2*5)+(3*6) = 32

   iteration2 ->
   List1 = [[A,1],[B,2],[C,3]]
   List2 = [[B,5],[C,6],[A,4]] #only second list shifts by one to the left
   sop = (1*5)+(2*6)+(3*4) = 29

   iteration2 ->
   List1 = [[A,1],[B,2],[C,3]]
   List2 = [[C,6],[A,4],[B,5]] #only second list shifts by one to the left
   sop = (1*6)+(2*4)+(3*5) = 29
```

Resulting list should show the following:

```
  resultlist = [32,29,29]
```

I am unable to figure out how to code this in python, can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Can you show what you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a variable (`offset`) that determines how much B is rotated, rather than physically shifting a list. The modulus operation on the index can be used to simulate a circular list.

```
def products(A, B):
    out = []
    n = len(A)
    for offset in range(n):
        out.append(sum( A[i] * B[ (i + offset) % n ] for i in range(n)))
    return out
```

The input is assumed to be arrays of numbers e.g. `products([1,2,3],[4,5,6])`

Comment: I am trying to do as you mentioned, but i am getting error message :(. It says "can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'". what am i missing? @feersum

Comment: @Explore_SDN Did you use flat lists of numbers as in the example call in the last line, rather than lists of lists like your post?

Comment: list of lists like i mentioned.@ freesum

Comment: You don't define the variables `A,B,C` in your code so it's not exactly clear how they are supposed to be used. If you just want to take the second element in a list as the numeric value, you could simply insert `[1]` after each of the `list[index]` expressions.

Comment: I need only the second value in list1 and list2 to be considered, so it does not matter what first element is .Can you please be more clear about "insert [1] after each of the list[index] expressions" ? How does the code change ?

Comment: Replace `A[i]` with `A[i][1]` and similary for `B[...]`, since `list[1]` gets the second element of `list`.

Answer (score 2):

You can `itertools.cycle` over List2, skipping one at the end of each loop:

```
from itertools import cycle

List1 = [['A',1],['B',2],['C',3]]
List2 = cycle([['A',4],['B',5],['C',6]])

resultlist = []
for _ in List1:
    resultlist.append(sum(a[1]*b[1] for a,b in zip(List1, List2)))
    next(List2)   # skip one of the cycle
print(resultlist)
```

Output:

```
[32, 29, 29]
```